How to run animation of a single object on click trigger in blender?
I am developing a blender environment of a restaurant with multiple objects like fridge, curtains etc. Each of them have some animations on them. I want to play a single animation like of a fridge opening, but the whole timeline plays. Is Animation nodes what i am missing here?
Can someone also explain What animation and geometry nodes are used for in blender.
